# How avoid module duplication by separated files on typeScript compilation?

Tags: module, compilation, typescript, minify, code-duplication

According to [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files) the compiled ES5 code looks like :

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {

    ...

})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {

    ...

})(Validation || (Validation = {}));

...
```

How avoid the duplication of Validation module to achieve :

```
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {

    ...

    ...

})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
```

It becomes really heavy with multipes files and it stays on minification... The __extends method for super constructor stays duplicated too.

Thank you

Comment: I do not think that there is a straight forward way to avoid this, except placing everything included in the Validation module in one single file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid this at the moment because the compiler combines files by simply appending them in the order you have specified (in reference comments).

Although there is visual duplication, there is still only a single object created in the global scope, so the duplication does not result in a noticeable performance problem and causes no memory issues.

If you have a large program and this is a problem for you, you should probably be considering external modules rather than internal modules as external modules are designed for bigger programs.